# Server connection error message for inactive server reappears regularly

Tags: network, macos, afp

This is the message that reappears very often:

[image]

The server in question ("Knorke") is my old MBP, which I reset (clean install) and sold about two years ago. On my current MBP, I connected to the old machine sporadically via AFP because I used it for testing purposes, being a spare machine and all.

Ever since then, I have not found a way to prevent this message from appearing occasionally. I tried cleaning the "recent servers" menu (from Finder's ⌘+K) and have been googling the problem on and off, but have found no solution.

Oddly enough, the message consistently reappears when I start Slack.app, and I believe it also occurs with other Electron-based apps, but that's just a guess on my part.

I am hesitant to try out all kinds of "cache cleaners" and the likes that float around on the internet, as the general opinion seems to be that they're doing more harm than good, so I would prefer a specific solution for this.

Comment: Is it in the Finder sidebar? Login items? Launch agent/daemon?

Comment: @JBis No, no, and I've checked `sudo launchctl list` but have not found anything that maches "knorke", so, probably not?

Comment: Hmm, hmm, and Do you have another user? Another Mac?

Comment: @JBis No other user on this machine, no other Mac on the network. Except for, you know, Knorke. Which hasn't been on the network for years. For what it's worth, the message also pops up when I'm on a different network IIRC.

Comment: No I mean do you have another Mac handy. And try creating a new test user and see if the symptoms occur.

Comment: @JBis oh, that makes more sense I guess. But now, I don't have another Mac handy. I'll create a second user on my machine and try some stuff then.

Comment: @JBis Created a test user, can open Slack and Resilio Sync (both Electron based) without triggering the message.

Comment: That's a good sign. Meaning worst come to worst you switch users. Try unchecking all login item on that user no matter what it is.

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25639/why-is-my-mac-constantly-trying-to-connect-to-another-server

Comment: Reboot into safe mode and check symptoms.

Comment: I removed all the login items from my account, even though none of them seemed related, and now the message does not appear when I open Slack. If you post that as an answer, I'd accept it. I don't understand it, but that seems to be the solution.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You issue is most likely a problem with login items.

1. Take note of your current login items
2. Try removing all login items and test.

3 . Add them back one by one until you find the one causing the problem.