# Mac keeps trying to connect to a server which is not on the network. Infinite pop-up sequence

Tags: macos, finder, smb

I have deleted all aliases, deleted my Preferences folder, Login Items, recent servers, and favorites linked to the server. It was for a job and someone from the company who managed servers set up this connection. I spent 1h 10min with another employee trying to figure out why this pop-up keeps appearing. We could not come up with a solution.

I launched my Mac in safe mode to make sure that it would stop popping up in that environment, which it thankfully did, since no automatic connections happen in safe mode. A solution I found out is to create a new user but I do not want to transfer all my data over.

Here is a photo of the error. It immediately pops up when I close it.

[image: Screenshot of dialog box showing a connection error to a server on the current network]

Edit: After running `$ sudo lsof | grep 192.168.1.2`

```
$ user1@MacBook-Pro ~ % sudo lsof | grep 192.168.1.2
                                                                                                                                
NetAuthSy  924        user1    4u     IPv4 0x471693aeba5a3217        0t0                 TCP 10.84.79.45:51057->192.168.1.2:microsoft-ds (SYN_SENT)

NetAuthSy  924        user1    5u     IPv4 0x471693aebb042a97        0t0                 TCP 10.84.79.45:51058->192.168.1.2:netbios-ssn (SYN_SENT)
```

Comment: What’s in System Preferences > Users & Groups > (your user account) > Login Items?

Comment: I already cleared the list. Nothing exists there.  I've tried all the generic things.

Comment: Right, I see it now in your original post - sorry for the noise. Can you share the output of the following commands? (Perhaps with a link to a PasteBin if it's too long.) **(1)** `launchctl list | grep -v com.apple` **(2)** `sudo launchctl list | grep -v com.apple`
 **(3)** `launchctl print system | grep -v com.apple`
 **(4)** `sudo launchctl print user/\`whoami\` | grep -v com.apple`
 **(5)** `kextstat | grep -v com.apple`

Comment: Its funny you say that because I just found the culprit. I will do the commands you just asked but please take a look at the edit I just made.

Comment: Here is the pastebin you requested pion: https://pastebin.com/B9YYKZfD

Comment: The question should standalone without pastebin as that will go away

Comment: Also if you have text to paste in please paste it as text so that we can read it not an image which I can't read

Comment: I changed the image into text. I do not understand what you mean by standalone without pastebin. I am new here! Sorry in advance. @mmmmmm

Comment: @elypsyo Let's see if we can get a hint about who is continuously asking for SMB share mounts. As soon as this message pops up next time, can you run the following and then share the output? `log show --info --debug --last 10m --predicate="eventMessage contains 'NetAuth' || process contains 'NetAuth' || sender contains 'NetAuth' || subsystem contains 'NetAuth'"`

Comment: Here is a similar question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/25639/30895

Comment: Hey @pion! Here is the new Pastebin with all the logs https://pastebin.com/tDsvUDyk .

Comment: I actually went through almost everything in that forum before making this one! My hopes were high but nothing worked in the end. @MartinR

Comment: @pion any luck with the new paste bin?

Answer (score 1):

I went into **Keychain Access.app** and searched for the string after server (in my case HomeAssistant, in your case 192.168.1.2) and found the entry with the term from network, and deleted it.